# Responsive CSS boxes

Tags: html, css

I have not done anything like this for a while. I was just wanting to check the way to make boxes based on the following:

- 2 rows
- 2 boxes on each row
- 100% to the page container width

Comment: Flexbox - https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ and media queries

Comment: I removed "the best 2018 way" from your question. That is asking for opinions and that is not allowed around here and you already have some people voting to close your question as opinion-based. Also, can you please show what you have tried?

Comment: You haven't specified whether the boxes should collapse when the window is resized. If not, you don't have to do anything except give the boxes 50% width and give them `display:inline-block`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is a hard question, 2018 just start, and I think that my solution is 2016 xD, but you request looks like something that can be done with 'flex'. If you really wanna get it deeper with flex, check this [post](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), you also can try with css grid, but I'm more fan of flex.

```css
.box {
  color: white;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.row div {
  flex: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}

.blue {
 background: blue;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="row red">
      <div>1</div>
      <div>2</div>
  </div>
   <div class="row blue">
      <div>3</div>
      <div>4</div>
   </div>
</div>
```